# Facebook Requests not starting my android app

Tags: facebook, request

I've gotten request sending to work on my android application, however even though my application is properly configured in the facebook dashboard, opening a request never starts my application!

I've set up my package name and class name properly - I start my facebook activity in my java code with the same package name and class name. I also set Facebook Login on and Deep Linking off. Is there anything that might be stopping my application from starting? I'm obviously following this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/app-link-requests/

Comment: I don't know if I can bump questions this way or if StackOverflow allows it but I could really use some help!